# Resolving an array of promises in parallel, with error handling

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a collection of promises or async functions, I need to manipulate slightly and then execute in parallel.

**The issue I am having is that I am unable to resolve the promises.**

```js
// Some dummy tasks:
const taskA = () => Promise.resolve(500);
const taskB = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(300));
};

// Push them into an array:
const tasks = [];

const registerTask = (name, task) => {
  tasks.push( async () => { 
    return { [name]: await task() };
  });
};

// trying to get the results
const runTasks = () => {
  const result = Promise.all(tasks).then(results => results);
  return result;
}

// usage
registerTask('taskA', taskA);
registerTask('taskB', taskB);

console.log(runTasks())
```

Following the successful resolution of promises ideally I would also like to handle errors individually for each task.

Comment: Sorry why the downvotes, please could you add a comment to explain? What use could it be to someone to just downvote?

Comment: Not sure why your question gets downvoted, but if you are using async await, why don't you wrap runTasks with async await? I think your runTasks will return before Promise.all gets resolved

Comment: I have tried that too, would really appreciate your help @Ihoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `registerTask` function pushes functions onto the `tasks` array, not `Promise` objects. If you change the function like this, it should work:

```
const registerTask = (name, task) => {
  const asyncFunc = async () => { 
    return { [name]: await task() };
  };
  tasks.push( asyncFunc() ); // This pushes a promise into 'tasks'
};
```

Your original code ended up with `tasks` being an array of functions that have not been called yet. When you call `Promise.all(tasks)` it ended immediately with `undefined` for each entry in the array because there were no `Promise` objects to wait on.

As for error handling, the `Promise.all` will fail with the first rejection or exception that happens. If you want to handle each task's individual error case, then you should do that in the `Promise` created in `registerTask` since doing it during the `Promise.all` is too late. It's hard to give an example since I'm not sure what kind of error handling would be appropriate for tasks, but perhaps something like this:

```
const registerTask = (name, task) => {
  const asyncFunc = async () => { 
    return { [name]: await task() };
  };
  const promise = asyncFunc()
    .catch(err => {
      return handleError(name, err);
    });
  tasks.push( promise ); 
};

function handleError(name, err) {
  console.log(`Task ${name} had error ${err}`);
  // don't re-throw the error if you want all tasks to complete
  // return some error object so you can see which tasks failed after they're done
  return {error: err, name: name};  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And this `tasks.push( asyncFunc() );` does not execute immediately?

Comment: yes, it does execute immediately by giving back a Promise object. But that Promise won't resolve until the function inside completes, which will not happen until the task completes because of the `await`.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` expects an array of promises and you are passing an **array of functions that returns a promise**. So change your promise `Promise.all` to receive the promise of each function:

```js
// Some dummy tasks:
const taskA = () => Promise.resolve(500);
const taskB = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(300));
};

// Push them into an array:
const tasks = [];

const registerTask = (name, task) => {
  tasks.push( async () => { 
    return { [name]: await task() };
  });
};

// trying to get the results
const runTasks = () => {
  const result = Promise.all(tasks.map(task => task())); // Execute the tasks to receive the promises
  return result;
}

// usage
registerTask('taskA', taskA);
registerTask('taskB', taskB);

runTasks().then((res) => {console.log(res)})
```

Comment: Does this `tasks.map(task => task())` not execute immediately?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? As long as you dont execute the task, the promise wont start. When you execute the task, the promise starts resolving.